# Bumblebee ubuntu 12.04 blender

Tags: bumblebee, blender, cuda

Hi there I used ironhide on 11.10 but in 12.04 I cannot install it because of the ppa (possibly removed) then I installed the bumblebee because blender doesn't working with cuda suport..

Does any one know a work around?

In ironhide I used optirun32 but in bumblebee that command doesn't exist.

I installed bumblebee from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Do you mean that blender doesn't work **without** CUDA support?
What exactly is the problem? Are there any error messages or codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ironhide` is  no longer maintained.

In bumblebee its only `optirun`. It works perfectly in my dell xps L502.

You don't need update from `ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` unless you are in ubuntu 11.04 and older. I recommend to  purge the ppa. Here is the updated [instruction](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu)

Also did you upgrade to 12.04 or did a clean install of 12.04? In case of upgrade you need to remove old ironhide mess, instruction [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu)

Comment: i done fresh install.. the problem is that if i use the blender from the PPA or repositories i cant use cuda processors, if i use the portable version from www.blender.com i can but i dont now wy is a little slow em in render widow mode.