# Install Nvidia driver for CUDA to use "GPU" option in Blender (ubuntu (13.10-) 14.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, blender

Same [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7765/do-i-realy-have-to-install-nvidias-driver-and-how-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment12700_7765) as on the Blender stackexchange site.

As a recap:

- I have to install the nvidia driver but how to do it? (repository or manually? And I already had problems with both, as said)
- My computer detects an other graphic card as the one that I have! (Maybe the reason why no proprietary drivers are purposed)

Every help is welcome!

It came out that the problem was that I have OPTIMUS. But in 14.04 it seems to be supported.

So, under 14.04 (on my external HDD) it detects my Nvidia driver OUT OF THE BOX!!!
But with Blender and cuda installed as said on [this site](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) and this driver:

[image]

I then installed Blender from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) as well as the CUDA driver from the same site.

Then, Blender detects the GPU!!!

[image: GPU detected]

But it says (Cycles mode with GPU rendering active):

[image: Cuda >= 2.0 only supported]

Even with Experimental on:

[image]

But on the site, thay say that Cuda < 2.0 is experimental:

[image: Cuda < 2.0 is experimental]

Should I wait, or could it help if I use another driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick sum up of the issues and their fixes:

- Optimus not supported by Ubuntu (13.10)

  -> Ubuntu 14.04 supports it out of the box!
- Blender doesn't detect CUDA

  -> Use the proprietary driver (accessible in the additional driver panel)
- Blender complains about CUDA 1.2. It only supports >=2.0

  -> Use Blender 2.96 or lower or install the CUDA toolkit

  -> AND use "Experimental" mode

=> It should work! :·)

For more informations: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10800/cuda-acceleration-with-cuda-1-2

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 2):

(Please see the update below)

For me, I had to:

- Install [proprietary drivers distributed by Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) ([recommended here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles))
- Install Blender via the ppa
- Install nvidia-modprobe (recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560768/no-cuda-after-nvidia-331-113-update)), without it Blender would throw cuda `cuinit: unknown error ubuntu`
- Reboot

So,

```
# Proprietary nvidia
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

# PPA for Blender
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender

# Update..
sudo apt-get update

# Install
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-modprobe blender

# Reboot
```

This was for Ubuntu 14.04, Blender 2.73,  GeForce GTX 650 Ti.

Otherwise, using the ubuntu nvidia stuff, building blender from source, running blender from the downloaded tar ball, etc.. all failed.

**UPDATE**

This all seemed to work until I tried to render, but then I got

```
Failed loading render kernel, see console for errors
```

Then on the console:

```
 Cycles shader graph connect: can only connect closure to closure (image_texture.Color to output.Surface).
 Unsupported CUDA version 5.5 detected, you need CUDA 6.5.
```

Installing CUDA 6.5 involved completely installing `nvidia-337` (otherwise you get a lot of `cuda-6-5 : Depends: .... (=....) but it is not going to be installed.` ([as shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533424/how-to-install-cuda-6-5-on-ubuntu-14-04)) and instead installing `nvidia-340`.

To install this [nvidia-340](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-latest-nvidia-340-46-via-ppa/),

```
# nvidia PPA for v340
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia

# Update
sudo apt-get update

# install nvidia and cuda
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 cuda-6-5

# Reboot
```

Other sites ([AskUbuntu on Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04), [R Tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda6.5-ubuntu), etc) recommend installing from the `.run`, but I had no issue just using `apt-get`.  The process did archive (rename) my xorg.conf file which disabled my edit file, but that was simple to revert.

Answer (score 1):

You can install nvidia-modprobe. The other way is to install Nvidia driver manually from Nvidia official site:

1. Uninstall previous Nvidia drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia-
   ```
2. Download latest version of your drever to your linux user folder, http://www.nvidia.ru/Download/Find.aspx
3. Install dependences:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` binutils pkg-config build-essential xserver-xorg-dev
   ```
4. Open blacklist:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
5. Add the lines to blacklists:

   ```
   blacklist vga16fb
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist rivafb
   blacklist nvidiafb
   blacklist rivatv
   ```
6. Open xorg config file:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
7. Add the lines to xorg config:

   ```
   Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Default Screen"
       DefaultDepth 24
   EndSection

   Section "Device"
       Identifier "Default Device"
       Driver "nvidia"
       Option "NoLogo" "True"
   EndSection

   Section "Module"
       Load "glx"
   EndSection
   ```
8. Stop x-server:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo service gdm stop
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo service kdm stop
   ```

   (depends on your linux version)
9. Install the driver (be aware that only one copy of nvidia driver script there is in your user home directory):

   ```
   sudo sh ./NVIDIA*
   ```

Trough the installing process do not agree for any automated features. Only manual things work.

10. Run x-server:

    ```
    sudo service lightdm start
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo service gdm start
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo service kdm start
    ```

    (depends on you linux version)
11. Run Blender and you will see CUDA option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question linked by you, you have GeForce GT 330M and ubuntu detected intel card as display driver. This concludes one thing, you have a laptop with optimus technology and you can not install nvidia drivers directly.If done, You will get a black screen.

Now I don't know what a blender is. But I guess this is a graphics intensive app which require powerful graphics processor.

The driver released by Nvidia doesn't support hybrid/optimus configuration. So there is unofficial work to get the power saving and finding a way to use  nvidia card. The result is [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/).

You can find the install & usage instruction - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

You can go through the following question before doing anything

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/35775)

A similar question but old - [Bumblebee ubuntu 12.04 blender](https://askubuntu.com/q/121962/35775)

maybe helpful :

[How can I get nVidia CUDA or OpenCL working on a laptop with nVidia discrete card/Intel Integrated Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/q/131506/35775)

More info - https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki

Comment: Ok! I'll test it! I keep you informed!

Comment: Ok, I tested it on an external HDD, with Ubuntu 13.10 installed on it. I installed Bumblebee and tested blender: nothing. Then, I installed the nvidia driver from ppa but nothing too! Should I wait for 14.04? (See [this site](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTU0MDI))

Comment: I installed 14.04 beta on my external HDD... And ubuntu detects my Nvidia graphics card OUT OF THE BOX!!! I used the additional drivers app to install the nvidia 331.38 version. Then I installed Blender with the [irie ppa](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) and CUDA like said on the same site. But then, Blender says:"CUDA device supported only with compute capability 2.0 or up, found 1.2". And in "Experimental" mode, it doesn't change anything too. Is it possible to change the version or something like this? Or should I wait the support (If I understand the Cycles wiki well)?

Comment: For the Nvidia graphics card I choose 331.38 but can choose 304.117 too. Which is best? And should I install the "-updates" version instead of the normal one? (I added a screenshot in the question)

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA driver has had support for Optimus on Ubuntu since 13.10. Your issue is that neither installing the NVIDIA drivers, nor installing Blender triggers the installation of the cuda toolkit. Open a terminal and issue the following command; sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit and it will enable the use of cuda in Blender.

Comment: I did install nvidia-cuda-toolkit (sorry, I only mentioned it in the comments below, in the response to Web-E). But it installs 1.2 ... (as I understood). I new it from this [site](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender). Do you think I could make something to make it work? (I'll update my question with the informations!) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sadly I have no other ideas. I'll look into it more and update my response if I find anything. This is an issue that plagued me so I know how frustrating this must be for you.

Comment: It is very frustrating,yes! Thank you very much for your help! :) I'll update the post if I have some news!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not like in 12.04 (precise) that if you download blender from blender.org (yes - I mean NOT installing but downloading the tar.gz thingy) unpack it and start directly blender from this file that the problem is solved?

I am using blender now since two years and **since these two years it always worked like that**. Which means: The installed blender version in ubuntu does **NOT** support CUDA and no update does while **the downloaded and "portable" version of blender** from blender.org does.

But do not ask me why that has not been changed.

Comment: That's exacly what I did recently, but it does NOT work with 2.70. BUT it WORKS with 2.96!!! :·). The only lasting problem is that, given that it doesn't install, I have to pass, at every launch, the load step (Blender loads something to let me use the graphics card). And my computer does not always pass it (overheating)! :( Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Strange. I work with 2.70a and it runs with CUDA support. It worked for me since almost 2 years now in all blender versions. But good to hear that it works for you with 2.96.