# No CUDA after NVIDIA 331.113 update

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I was using NVIDIA 331.38 with CUDA toolkit 6.5 and all my applications were able to detect GPU. After NVIDIA 331.113 update, CUDA is not working. Anyone else experiencing the same? Thank you

Comment: Could you try if the applications can use the GPU if you run then as root using sudo?

Answer (score 7):

I got OpenCL working with the nvidia 331.113 update.
You have to install `nvidia-modprobe` and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me tks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error this morning after updating from 331.38 to 331.113.
CUDA doesn't work anymore for me in Blender.

Blender displays the following error when switched to Cycles engine:

> CUDA cuInit: Unknown error

I suspect the bug is caused by the following change in nvidia-331.113 package:

```
 * debian/templates/control.in:
    - Make libcuda1-$flavour depend on nvidia-$flavour-uvm.
```

**Edit:** I've just downgraded all the nvidia-331 packages back to version 331.38, and CUDA is working again under Blender.

Comment: How did you downgraded all the nvidia-331 packages? Was looking for info to rollback the driver

Comment: No worries, i managed to do it with the Synaptic Package Manager. CUDA is back \m/

Comment: To downgrade packages in ubuntu http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/